# Ghostscript does not read pdf file

Tags: ghostscript, langchain

I have over 10 pdf in my input folder. I am trying to ask Ghostscript read 10 pdf that are in input folder and then transfer them to output pdf folder. However, it only reads 3 pdf files. What is the solution here? Thanks.

Ghostscript only reads 3 pdf, remaining 7 pdf are not read by Ghostscript. It is not transferred to output folder.

This is the issue I am getting:

**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
huggingface/tokenizers: The current process just got forked, after parallelism has already been used. Disabling parallelism to avoid deadlocks...
To disable this warning, you can either:
- Avoid using `tokenizers` before the fork if possible
- Explicitly set the environment variable TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=(true | false)
GPL Ghostscript 9.56.1 (2022-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2022 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
GPL Ghostscript 9.56.1: Cannot open X display `(null)'.
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.

This is the code I am running:

```
"import os

pdf_folder_path = './pdf' # Replace with the path to your PDF files directory
output_folder_path = './output' # Replace with the path to your output directory

if not os.path.exists(output_folder_path):
   os.makedirs(output_folder_path)

for file_name in os.listdir(pdf_folder_path):
    if file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
      input_path = os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, file_name)
      output_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, file_name[:-4] + '_output.pdf')
        !gs -o $output_path -sDEVICE=pdfwrite $input_path

loaders = [UnstructuredPDFLoader(os.path.join(output_folder_path, fn)) for fn in
os.listdir(output_folder_path)]
 loaders
```

I was expecting to have 10 pdf files read by Ghostscript and transferred into the output folder.

Comment: "**** Unable to open the initial device" There's your problem right there. Furthermore, at the end of the text you quoted: " Cannot open X display `(null)'. **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting" So your problem is that you are trying to use the X display device and don't have an X installation. I cannot figure out what your command line invocation of Ghostscript looks like from your code, but it looks to me like you haven't specified a device, so you'll get the default, which is often the X device Try specifying the one you want.

Comment: So I finally deciphered the command line, and you do specify the pdfwrite device. So it looks like the problem is in your code somehow which is ending up not using pdfwrite. Is this synchronous or are you spawning multiple simultaneous processes ?